# Fatal error: Index out of range when receive nil data which I marked as optional

Tags: swift, null, option-type, iso

Hi I have some issue relate to index out of range in a array of my data model. As long as the `images = []` is empty, the app crashes.

so this is the code in my UIViewController's table view.

```
        
        if let urlString = vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles[indexPath.row].images[0] {
            
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            cell.vehicleImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil)
        } else {
            let url = URL(string: "https://vehicleimage-insure.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/defaultCarIcon.png")
            cell.vehicleImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil)
        }
```

this is my data model for the image property, I have marked it optional:

```
struct UserVehicles: Codable {
    let id: String 
    let images: [String?]
    let userId: String
}
```

error message is as below picture:

[image]

I checked the debug output, as follows:

[image]

I mean I made the if let syntax, shouldn't the error be captured? Please give me some hints how can I fix this error?

Comment: No, if `if let` will check the optional, not the out of range. Let's start by checking which one is out of index: `userVehicles` or `images`? That's `images` according to your error. Check if it's not empty first, or use `.images.first`, since you have an `if let`, that should work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider all the places where this can go wrong:

```
if let urlString = vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles[indexPath.row].images[0]
```

Well, `vehicleList` might be `nil`. But that's no problem; the `if let` takes care of that.

Next, you've got an array reference `userVehicles[indexPath.row]`. Well, I suppose there might not be that many objects in the array.

Finally, you've got another array reference, `images[0]`. But the array might be empty.

So we can check all of those safely:

```
if let vList = vehicleList, // avoid `nil`
    vList._embedded.userVehicles.count > indexPath.row,
    vList._embedded.userVehicles[indexPath.row].images.count > 0 {
        // now it is safe
        let urlString = vlist._embedded.userVehicles[indexPath.row].images[0]
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        cell.vehicleImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil)
    } else {
        // use placeholder URL
}
```

(You might need to improve on that code if some of your objects are themselves possibly `nil`, but you already know how to do that.)

Answer (score 2):

if let statement will check if an optional statement is nil or not.

When you try to access an element of array at an index which does not exists, it does not return nil but you get an index out of range error.

If you want to access to elements in array safely, you should perform array size check before accessing the index.

```
if list.count > 0 {
    let listItem = list[0]
    // do something
}
```

Or implement an extension for Collection to access safely.

```
extension Collection {

    /// Returns the element at the specified index if it is within bounds, otherwise nil.
    /// Sample: `list[safe: index]`
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

then you can use if let with it since this subscript will return an optional.

```
if let listItem = list[safe: 0] {
    // do something
}
```